# Getting error while adding new routes, path is required in a route configuration

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I wanted to add the dynamic routes and use the same component for all the dynamic routes. I have tried the following code to render the components, but I have got the error that says:

> [vue-router] "path" is required in a route configuration.

What is the proper way of adding the dynamic routes and display the same components?

```js
const Foo = {
  template: '<div>Foo</div>'
}
const Home = {
  template: '<div>Home</div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: Home
  }]
})
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#vue-app",
  methods: {
    viewComponent: function(path, method) {
      debugger;
      let tf = `${path}/${method}`;

      let newRoute = {
        path: tf,
        name: `${path}_${method}`,
        components: {
          Foo
        },
      }
      this.$router.addRoute([newRoute])

    },

  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="vue-app">
  <a v-on:click="viewComponent('api/contact','get')">ddd</a>

  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Main problem is you are passing array into `addRoute`
2. Second problem is missing `/` at the beginning of the path (without it, you will get a "Non-nested routes must include a leading slash character" error)
3. Finally use `$router.push` to go to the new route

```js
const Foo = {
  template: '<div>Foo</div>'
}
const Home = {
  template: '<div>Home</div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: Home
  }]
})
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: "#vue-app",
  methods: {
    viewComponent: function(path, method) {
      let tf = `/${path}/${method}`;

      let newRoute = {
        path: tf,
        name: `${path}_${method}`,
        component: Foo,
      }
      this.$router.addRoute(newRoute)
      this.$router.push({ name: newRoute.name })
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="vue-app">
  <a v-on:click="viewComponent('api/contact','get')">ddd</a>

  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: I had got the new problem now it says `[vue-router] Duplicate named routes definition:`, when i tried to render the same route again.